# Add an autoincrement value to a MS Access query in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a `Sales` query that outputs the following columns :

```
Customer | StockCode | TotalSales | TrnYear
```

(Note:, all the four column values taken together create a unique row)

I would like to add a autoincrement ID column to the above result using a SQL MS Access query. I do not want to use a autoincrement table but rather just generate the autonumber ID using access SQL.

I want to end up with a result that will have the following columns :

```
ID | Customer | StockCode | TotalSales | TrnYear
```

Sample data listed below: (Please forgive the lack of table formatting)

I start with:

```
Customer | StockCode | TotalSales | TrnYear

ABC      | DK-Stk1   | $125,000   | 2013 

ABC      | DK-Stk2   | $15,000    | 2013

CDA      | PK-Stk1   | $99,000    | 2012

RDE      | PK-Stk2   | $15,000    | 2013
```

I want to end up with the below result:

```
ID | Customer | StockCode | TotalSales | TrnYear

1  | ABC      | DK-Stk1   | $125,000   | 2013 

2  | ABC      | DK-Stk2   | $15,000    | 2013

3  | CDA      | PK-Stk1   | $99,000    | 2012

4  | RDE      | PK-Stk2   | $15,000    | 2013
```

Thanks for help with this.

Comment: Why would you not just use a temp table to do this if you need it that badly?

Comment: Please explain how to do this using a temp table. The result of this query will have to be generated in real time, and i would like to know if there is a big overhead in processing if I use a temp table.

Comment: Drop table if it exists, create table at run time, append the records from your query to the new table and select from that table (using VBA).